# MySQL - Only populating from one table dependent on value

Tags: mysql

Sorry haven't used SQL in some time. I have three tables about superheros. I want to get the superhero name and retreive a tv name from either Marvel or DC dependent on the results. However the query is populating both columns when retrieving the information when I should just have one entry per name. My View is:

```
CREATE VIEW `herotelly` AS 
SELECT distinct(a.Name), b.Title as showname, c.Title
FROM superheroes a, marveltv b, dctv c
WHERE a.Name = b.Superhero or a.Name = c.Superhero;
```

However the result is

```
"Superman"  "Spidey Super Stories"  "Adventures of Superman"   
"Batman"    "Spidey Super Stories"  "Batman"      
"Catwoman"  "Spidey Super Stories"  "Batman" 
"Robin"     "Spidey Super Stories"  "Batman"
```

But I only want one result for example in the first row I just want superman, with the second column empty and then the result in the third column.

Any help is much appreciated.

Neil.

Comment: Show the result you expect. It's not all that clear since your `SELECT` statement says you want your second column to be `b.TITLE as showname` but you are saying you want it to be blank.

Comment: You should do two separate joins, and combine them with `UNION`.

Comment: "distinct" is **NOT** a function. It is a qualifier to the word `select` as in `select distinct` which works across the entire row. Parentheses used after distinct are just ignored ie.  `SELECT DISTINCT a.Name, b.Title as showname, c.Title`

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a cross product between both `marveltv` and `dctv`, and then returning the title from both. Instead of joining both tables at once, use `UNION` of two separate joins.

```
SELECT a.name, b.title
FROM superheroes AS a
JOIN marveltv AS b ON a.name = b.superhero
UNION
SELECT a.name, b.title
FROM superheroes AS a
JOIN dctv AS b ON a.name = b.superhero
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help both of you it's much appreciated. Neil.

Answer (score 1):

This query should give you what you want. Without sample data it's hard to be certain... It makes a `UNION` of the two title tables and then `JOIN`s that to the superhero table:

```
CREATE VIEW `herotelly` AS 
SELECT s.Name, t.Title
FROM superheroes s
JOIN (SELECT Superhero, Title FROM marveltv
      UNION
      SELECT Superhero, Title FROM dctv) t
  ON s.Name = t.Superhero
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks this solution worked for me. Neil.

CREATE VIEW `herotelly` AS 
SELECT s.Name, t.Title
FROM superheroes s
JOIN (SELECT Superhero, Title FROM marveltv
      UNION
      SELECT Superhero, Title FROM dctv) t
  ON s.Name = t.Superhero